# Type declaration preference for React components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm fairly new to TypeScript.  Which of the following declarations is preferred in the community and why?

```
interface MyComponentProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

// Option 1
const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = ({ children }) => <>{children}</>;

// Option 2
const MyComponent = ({ children }: MyComponentProps) => <>{children}</>;
```

I feel that option 1 may provide more typing information.  However, option 2 seems easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FC` type already includes the `children` prop so, in this specific case, just declaring it as an `FC` type would be enough.

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react';

const Component : FC = ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>;
```

If you need anything more than that then you can use the first option like so:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react';

interface ComponentProps {
  title: string;
  subtitle?: string;
}

const Component : FC<ComponentProps> = ({ title, subtitle }) => (
  <div>
    <span>{title}</span>
    <span>{subtitle}</span>
  </div>
);
```

The first option is pretty much the only way I've seen components props declared in a lot of different projects.

The `FC` type (which is an alias for `FunctionComponent` by the way) provides a couple of useful declarations which would be lost in the second option.